# Scaling object using delta time?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, time

I'm trying to scale and object with some easing.  Which works fine.  But I also want to apply a delta time value to the actual scaling.  I am just puzzled where to add the value.

Here's the scale easing code:

```
scale  += (MIN_SCALE  - scale) * 0.6;
```

How would I apply the delta time value?  It's not like when addressing a position in the way as:

```
x += deltaTime * speed;
```

This is more of a general question applying to most languages I would think.  But in my case I am using ActionScript 3.

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably multiply it by another variable, that changes (increases, decreases) as time passes.

```
scale  += (MIN_SCALE  - scale) * 0.6 * scaleModifier;
```

// Change the value of `scaleModifier` using any timers:

```
scaleModifier = deltaTime * 0.1;
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing!  That did the trick.  Thanks a lot mate.  Would rep you if I could!